# Как корректно подключить модуль в тег Head?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть вот такой js файл который необходимо подключить в теге `head`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После некорректной(как я понимаю) попытки сделать это я получаю сделующий результат на локалке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы можем увидеть что во первых в теге `head` существует какой то `error`.

Так же при попытке подгрузить в конец тега `body` данный скрипт
(это сделано только с целью эксперимента) - мне не удается как минимум получить подключение через абсолютный путь `(__nuxt/.....)`

Вопрос:
Что я упускаю из виду и каким образом корректно можно подключить необходимый `js` файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, `/js/gtm.js` читается как абсолютный путь, где первый слеш означает корень диска. Если вы пишите относительный адрес и папка `js`находится на одном уровне с импортирующим файлом, должно быть `./js/gtm.js`

Comment: Хорошо. Если мы представим, что данный проект лежит в корне диска(домена) - как корректно должен быть прописан путь(в теге head) с вашей точки зрения?

Comment: Даже если проект в корне диска, `./js/gtm.js` всё равно должно работать. И относительные пути обычно предпочтительнее, потому что они остаются рабочими и при перемещении проектов локально. Хотя у меня тут не очень много опыта, может, кто-то поправит.